# how can I make the changes made by the user in the GUI persistant?

Tags: python, persistence, appsettings

Ho so Iam working on a project(Graphical user interface) and there are some settings like if you want it to be darkmode or not. What i want to do is to make the changes made by the user persistent. So if the user wants the interface to be darkmode he should click on it(which is already implemented) but everytime he opens the interface it should always be in the darkmode(ofc if he wants to change it afterwards he can). So I am looking for packages or some approach that can help me do that

I googled but didn't find anything that can help me

Comment: It's likely that a config file is generated by such kind of projects.
For Linux it can be in the user `$HOME` directory under the `.config` folder.
For example for the `neofetch` program I can find this config file : `.config/neofetch/config.conf`
The file contains default values that one can uncomment if if wants to customize the app behavior.
The file format can be plain text, json, yaml.

Comment: You can use configparser https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html to write the settings to a file everytime the user changes some setting (like from light to dark mode). Then when you start your application, you have to go through the file and check all configurations and apply them to your application on startup.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.